# Create Multiple Unique Classes Using Loops (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, loops, class, object

hello. I'm trying to create multiple unique instances of an object using a loop. Here's my code:

```
class Person: 
    def __init__(self, name, age, hobby, instrument):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.hobby = hobby
        self.instrument = instrument

    def printInfo(self): 
        print(f"Name: {self.name}\nAge: {self.age}\nHobby: {self.hobby}\nInstrument: {self.instrument}")  
        print() 

names = ["Adonis", "Michael", "George", "Towney", "Katrina", "Slestria", "Harry"]
ages = [17, 18, 16, 16, 17, 18, 16]
hobbies = ["Karate", "Music", "Knitting", "Programming", "Skiing", "Egging homes", "Doing magic"]
instruments = ["Alto saxophone", "Clarinet", "Oboe", "Trombone", "Flute", "Trumpet", "Percussion"]
```

Instead of having to do the following:

```
p1 = Person("Adonis", 17, "Karate", "Alto saxophone") 
p2 = Person("Michael", 18, "Music", "Clarinet") 
p3 = Person("George", 16, "Knitting", "Oboe") 
.
.
.
```

I'd like to know if there was an easier way. In the end, I'd like to be able to do this for all objects:

```
p3.printInfo() 

Name: George 
Age: 16 
Hobby: Knitting 
Instrument: Oboe
```

I don't know if this is possible. I'm still new to classes and objects, so some criticism and a kick in the right direction would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a *bad* idea to assign persons to individual variables. You can construct a list of persons using list comprehension:

```
persons = [Person(*info) for info in zip(names, ages, hobbies, instruments)]
```

Here, `zip(...)` combines your four lists into a list of 4-element tuples. Each tuple from the list is sequentially passed to the constructor as four separate parameters (the `*` converts a tuple of four items to four parameters).

```
persons[3].printInfo()
#Name: Towney
#Age: 16
#Hobby: Programming
#Instrument: Trombone
```

Comment: Okay, thank you for the advise! I have another question, if you don't mind: What if I want to remove a person entirely from all lists? Is there a way I can do that in one fell swoop instead of deleting all of the person's corresponding indexes in the other lists? What I mean is this: If I want to take out, say, George, instead of going: 

names.remove('George'), and so on for the other lists, can I do something easier? Thanks again!

Comment: Can you instruct me on how to do that in this case to give me a start?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the zip function to aggregate all data necessary to each person and then

```
create class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age, hobby, instrument):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.hobby = hobby
        self.instrument = instrument

    def printInfo(self):
        print(f"Name: {self.name}\nAge: {self.age}\nHobby: {self.hobby}\nInstrument: {self.instrument}")
        print()

names = ["Adonis", "Michael", "George", "Towney", "Katrina", "Slestria", "Harry"]
ages = [17, 18, 16, 16, 17, 18, 16]
hobbies = ["Karate", "Music", "Knitting", "Programming", "Skiing", "Egging homes", "Doing magic"]
instruments = ["Alto saxophone", "Clarinet", "Oboe", "Trombone", "Flute", "Trumpet", "Percussion"]

counter = 1
for name, age, hobbie, instrument  in zip(names, ages, hobbies, instruments):
    globals()["p{}".format(counter)] = Person(name , age, hobbie, instrument)
    counter += 1
```

The relevant variables from the globals() dictonery look like

```
{'p1': <__main__.Person object at 0x02C8EE30>, 'p2': <__main__.Person object at 0x02C8EE70>, 'p3': <__main__.Person object at 0x02C8EEB0>, 'p4': <__main__.Person object at 0x02C8EEF0>, 'p5': <__main__.Person object at 0x02C8EF30>, 'p6': <__main__.Person object at 0x02C8EF70>, 'p7': <__main__.Person object at 0x02C8EFB0>}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can create a for loop with the list of persons

```
p1,p2,p3 =list
all_list=[p1,p2,p3]

for i in all_list :
    i=person()
```

then you can run method